# Uninstall R from Docker image

Tags: docker, r

I have tried:

> sudo apt-get remove r-base
>
> sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
>
> delete everything in .libPaths()

The thing is, I'm using a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/) which came with R installed in it. When I run those commands, the terminal prompts:

> Package 'r-base-core' is not installed, so not removed

The reason why I'm trying to uninstall R from a container built for using R is that what I really need is to use Oracle R Enterprise and it only works for R version 3.3.0. The version that came already installed in the container is 3.6.0

With this set, I can think of 2 possible solutions to my problem:

1. Remove everything in the paths that .libPaths() show and hope that works. Would be awesome if someone could confirm if that would work before I try it and mess everything up.
2. Find a way to downgrade to 3.3.0 version from 3.6.0 version so I don't have to uninstall and re-install R again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look on a [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/dockerfile) which is being used for that particular image, there's really no `r-base` or `r-base-core` packages. It looks like `r` comes as a part of `rstudio-server` package.

You might want to use older version of `rstudio-server` package. Normally it's not a good idea to mess with files from deb-packages manually.

PS. Instead of applying change to already existing container, it might be much better to build your own image based on modified version of Dockerfile which is used for rstudio.

Comment: In the end that is the best option, you're right. I wanted to cut corners by changing directly within the container but the use of Docker is recommended for what you just said, building containers from images that I can tune myself. Thanks for the answer.